# Use my ssh key to sign git commits

Tags: gpg

I am trying to setup automatic signing of git commits with gpg. I have a private/public key pair, that I use to authenticate to the server and be able to push commits. I would like to use the same key for signing commits (because someone could authenticate as themselves, but push a commit with my name on it).

Is that possible? `gpg --list-keys` returns nothing!

Comment: A quick altagoobingleduckgo turns up http://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable and thence to http://budts.be/weblog/2012/08/ssh-authentication-with-your-pgp-key which indicates you need a GPG keypair, then to export that to SSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can auto-sign commits by [setting the `commit.gpgsign` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20628522/120999).

However, you need a *PGP*-type key, not an SSH key.  What you *can* do is [use gpg-agent as an ssh agent](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~guenther/gpg-agent-for-ssh.html).

Answer (score 5):

With the release of git 2.34 you can now use your [ssh key to sign git commits](https://github.blog/2021-11-15-highlights-from-git-2-34/#tidbits).